# spring-security removes principal

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

My spring-security config:

```
<http request-matcher="regex">
    <anonymous granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>

    <intercept-url pattern="/admin*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/consultant*" access="ROLE_CONSULTANT" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_CONSULTANT"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/chat*" access="ROLE_CONSULTANT,ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />

    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/consultant" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" 
        username-parameter="username" 
        password-parameter="password"
        login-processing-url="/login-check"/>
    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    <session-management>
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" session-registry-alias="sessionRegistry" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/>
    </session-management>
</http>
```

There are three roles in my application: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_CONSULTANT and ROLE_ANONYMOUS. I want to differentiate the access between them in such a way that ROLE_ADMIN, for example, wouldn't be able to open /consultant.

But i've encountered a problem with logined ROLE_CONSULTANT that opens some /chat links: on the /consultant page he is logined and after the forwarding to /chat page he becomes anonymous.

Theese lines i found in debug log:

```
chat?action=startChat at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
DEBUG [qtp1591019083-16] (SessionRegistryImpl.java:164) - Removing principal ...
```

So the question is why is this happening and how should i avoid it?

P.S.: I use spring-security 3.2.0RC2.

Comment: A few things you should probably clarify: Why do you think this message is a problem? Why are you exposing the SessionRegistry reference - if you're using it what are you doing with it? What is 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter' - there's no sign of it in this configuration? Why are you using a 'regex' matcher? Please edit your question to clarify these points.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :)
The message itself is not a problem, the problem is that the logined user becomes anonymous (i.e. "unlogined") after transition to another page.
I use SessionRegistry to get all the logined users, that's all.
WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter is default filter that present in the filter chain, i didn't explicitly configured it.
I changed the default matcher to regex while i was trying to fix the actual problem (i thought maybe i had written the patterns wrong).

Comment: Please check your log files for the following line: "Registering session ..  for principal ..." closely before "Removing principal" (checking the source of SessionRegistryImpl shows that spring security either received a SessionDestroyedEvent or tried to create a new one), my blind guess is that through the <<concurrency-control> settings, the session is killed on page (controller?) change